# Issue with an image loaded from web and saved into disk not appearing until I unplug the phone and plug it back in

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8.1

I thought I had it working fine, since I had my phone unplugged and when I plugged it back in I had all the pictures working, however, when I tried to work with them, seems, it is not working as expected, since the image.Properties.Width = 0.

Can you guys help me out to have it working, please?

This is the code:

Main Page

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private GetFromJson get = new GetFromJson();
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        get.GetFullResponse(GlobalVariables.apiUrl + "/" + "api/"+ GlobalVariables.shopping + "/general");


    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnIngresarConEmail_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(IngresarConEmail));
    }

    private void btnCrearCuenta_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(CrearCuenta));
    }


}
```

Global Variables

```
public class GlobalVariables
{
    public static string UserName;
    public static string EmailAddress;
    public static string Password;
    public static string Name;
    public static IList<Medio> Medios;
    public string Stores;

    public static string apiUrl = "http://ec2-52-8-2-140.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com";
    public static string shopping = "1";

}
```

GetFromJson

```
public class GetFromJson
{

    private Medio medio = new Medio();
    public async void GetFullResponse(string address)
    {
        try
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();

            var uri = new Uri(address);
            Debug.WriteLine(uri);
            var Response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
            var statusCode = Response.StatusCode;

            Response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var ResponseText = await Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            string myJson = ResponseText;

            Debug.WriteLine(myJson);

            medio.deserializeAndConvert(myJson);

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Medio

```
public class Medio
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string img { get; set; }
    public string medios_id { get; set; } 

    public void deserializeAndConvert(string aaa)
    {
        JObject myGeneral = JObject.Parse(aaa);
        IList<JToken> results = myGeneral["resp"]["medios"].Children().ToList();

        IList<Medio> searchResults = new List<Medio>();
        foreach (JToken result in results)
        {
            Medio searchResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Medio>(result.ToString());
            searchResults.Add(searchResult);
            Debug.WriteLine(searchResults);

        }


        Debug.WriteLine(searchResults.Count);
        GlobalVariables.Medios = searchResults;

        var selected = GlobalVariables.Medios.Where(item => item.img!=null);
        Debug.WriteLine(GlobalVariables.Medios[0].ToString());

    }
}
```

And the one that saves the pics into the disk (the Windows Phone internal memory)

```
public sealed partial class CrearCuenta : Page
{

    public CrearCuenta()
    {

        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        QueryPicturesToShow();
    }

    public async void QueryPicturesToShow()
    {
        var pics = from medio in GlobalVariables.Medios
                   where medio.img != null
                   select new { Name = medio.name, Id = medio.id, Picture = medio.img };

        foreach (var item in pics)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(item.Name);
            Debug.WriteLine(item.Id);
            Debug.WriteLine(item.Picture);



            await savePicToDisk(item.Picture, item.Name, item.Id);
        }
    }

    private async Task savePicToDisk(string picAddress, string picName, string picId)
    {
        StorageFolder folder = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFolderAsync("carpetaFunciona", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync((picName + picId + ".png"), CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        string url = GlobalVariables.apiUrl + picAddress;

        Debug.WriteLine(url);
        System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

        byte[] responseBytes = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);

        var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);

        using (var outputStream = stream.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
        {
            DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(outputStream);
            writer.WriteBytes(responseBytes);
            await writer.StoreAsync();
            await outputStream.FlushAsync();

        }
        Debug.WriteLine(file.Name);
    }
```

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is your service, all images are null:

[image: Null images]

Comment: I found the problem.... it was a matter of time... the images come after the user fills in an email, username and password... I was skipping that, but once I took the time to do so, the images were all there (most of them are null but the guy working in the backend is updating them as fast as possible)